# Change request of a behaviour implemented deep in the call stack but is configured in the first calls

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, refactoring, clean-code, hexagonal-architecture

**Problem**: I have a complex system with many layers of abstractions. I need a different behaviour low in the abstractions, but to be configured high in the abstraction.

**Solution 1**: Having a parameter to define the chosen behaviour and pass this parameter down in the abstraction until the method that uses it.

**Solution 2**: Have a configuration module set high in the abstraction and the module low in the abstraction have access the configuration module.

**Solution 3**: Strategy Design Pattern?

According to the Clean Code book the solution 1 is bad because a function shouldn't have control flags as parameters, the different path should become a new function. Doing so in this case would duplicate what else is called in this function and in the underlying ones.

The problem with the solution 2 is the scope of the configuration, if it's too high it becomes hard to test the code as I have a dependency that I can not inject, if I inject I'm kind of in the solution 1. Also following an Hexagonal Architecture I could be forcing my Application layer to depend on external modules, for example if the user access the different code paths depending from which page he accessed the functionality.

A friend recommended me to take a look in the Strategy pattern, but for what I remember it needs to pass a reference to the implementation that's going to be used and in the end is similar to injecting the dependency.

#### My conclusion

I feel that the solution 2 is better as I can define in which level of the abstraction I will have this configuration module, but I would like to know if the problem is solved for a better design pattern or refactoring strategy.

Comment: sometimes with these problems when look at the specific case there is a solution which cant be seen from the generic case

Comment: the very nature of an abstraction is supposed to hide these low level behaviours, if you need to change them you might be doing something wrong

Comment: I understand the point and I agree, but the problem is in a context that I don't have all the information since the begin. It's a mix of architecture and refactoring question I think.

Comment: I think you need to add some context. atm you question is "consider this contradiction. whats the solution"

Comment: Does your solution use [IoC or DI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596300/where-exactly-is-the-difference-between-ioc-and-di) at all? Seems to me you just need to inject a delegate or class that provides the behavior.

Comment: Your question heavily begs for a concrete example.

Answer (score 1):

Passing configuration parameters from "higher" layers to "lower" layers (instead of letting lower layers access directly configuration data) is fine. But this is about **layers**, not about functions.

What you found in Uncle Bob's Clean Code book about control flags is purely meant for functions - each function is part of a class, a module, a component or a layer, and when the class, module, component or layer is constructed or initialized, then it is perfectly ok to pass configuration parameters from a  higher level unit to this lower level unit, as part of of the construction or initialization process. For example, if the unit is one class, one can pass a configuration flag through the constructor and store its value inside a member variable. AFAIK there is no recommendation in the Clean Code book against this kind of design.

Functions inside such a layer can then access this layer-specific configuration directly, without getting the value passed as a parameter. Or the initialization code of the layer/class/module/component takes the configuration and uses it to build a certain strategy object. That is what the strategy pattern is for - it is a clean way of implementing configuration-dependent behaviour inside a layer.